# How to make universal apps in Gamesalad for iOS?

Tags: ios, resolution, ios-universal-app, 2d-games

I have just started using Gamesalad to make iOS apps. I would like to make a Universal app, but there is only an iPhone OR iPad option. So how do I make one ?
* I would like Resolution Independence on *

Thanks,
Luke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't matter, I found it. Just make it in iPad at full iPad res, then Gamesalad will scale it down for the device being used.